# if(data != null) NOT IS NULL being ignored

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am learning to program in DART using FLUTTER
but I'm in a situation I don't understand,
I'm using this function to get SharedPreferences data

```
Iterable decoded = jsonDecode(data);
List<Item> result = decoded.map((x) => Item.fromJson(x)).toList();
```

but if I try to send being null will give error!
so I put this if

```
if(data != null)
```

but it is passing even being null

my code

```
Future load() async{

    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var data = prefs.getString('data');

    // justing for testing
    print(data);

    if(data != null){

      // another test
      print("NOT IS NULL");
      Iterable decoded = jsonDecode(data);
      List<Item> result = decoded.map((x) => Item.fromJson(x)).toList();
      setState(() {
        widget.itens = result;
      });

    }else{
      print("IS NULL");
    }
  }
```

and, look the debug log

```
Restarted application in 3.464ms.
flutter: [null]
flutter: NOT IS NULL
```

sorry my bad english

Comment: try to get specified value and check it again

Answer (score 1):

Note that `print(data)` did not print `null`; it printed `[null]` (i.e. with square brackets).

This means that `data` is *not* `null`.  It is a `List` containing a single `null` element.

Answer (score 0):

List containing a single **null** element.Here data is not null.
Try to add new elements in the sharedPreference and test again.

Answer (score -1):

Try just `if(data)`, because the value can be undefined and in that case, it is a false value but not equals null.

Comment: Look like your data is an array with one element that is null, but the variable is not really null.

Comment: estava olhando isso agora mesmo 
ele retorna [null] não null, testei com uma var aleatoria e retorna apenas null 
quero so ver como vou sair dessa kkkk 

mas bom ja ajudou muito